# git cherry-pick failed on a merge commit

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I tried to cherry-pick using

```
git cherry-pick a00f63
```

but got a message

```
error: commit a00f63... is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

`a00f63` is indeed a merge commit. After trying

```
git cherry-pick -m a00f63
```

I got

```
error: option `mainline' expects a number greater than zero
```

What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-cherry-pick%5D+error%3A+commit+is+a+merge+but+no+%22-m%22+option+was+given

Comment: `git cherry-pick -m1 a00f63`